# Java: A filterable file browser for a multiplatform program?

Tags: java, filedialog, file-browser

FilenameFilters don't work with fileDialog in Windows apparently. Is there any other option for a file browser that is filterable and works across Windows, OSX, and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using swing? You can try [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

Comment: Does it work well with OSX? From what I've read it seemed like filedialog was preferred. Aren't there any other options that call the native file chooser?

Comment: Have you tried `fileDialog.setFile("*.jpg");` instead of setFilenameFilter? It should be a workaround for your problem.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't filter the files displayed in the file chooser. I could still see and select mp4 files for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it will helful to you.

```
saveFileDialog.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter(){
      enter code here`@Override
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
      {
           return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg");
      }
});
```

Comment: The documentation says FilenameFilters don't work on Sun's default implementation on Windows. I tried it anyway, but it didn't seem to work.